# How to statically and dynamically link libraries C / C++

Tags: c++, c

I just finished learning c and c++ and I find myself in love with the two middle-level languages. So I decided to do a project involving the two languages. But I stumbled when it came to linking .lib and .dll files to the executable files. I know that when using visual studio, we just use a #pragma comment (lib, libname) . But how do we link using g++ ,say, tokenizer.lib to main.cpp?? I'm working on Windows. Thanks in advance

Comment: finished learnig? Is it even possible to do that? :D But to the point - you need to add -lmylib to link lib to your program (-l and then library name)

Comment: You are looking for the `-l` option. Try `g++ ... -L/path/to/tokenizer_lib_dir -ltokenizer` or something similar.

Comment: You're looking for the GCC manual => http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC, specifically http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options, which specifies the -l flag to specify a link library. You can find tutorials like this all around => http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse451/W97/Section/gcctutorial.html

Comment: "I just finished learning c and c++"... "But I stumbled when it came to linking .lib and .dll files"... **Not even a single contradiction...**

Comment: Thanks you guyz. The command worked. You see no one around me knows these "coding" stuff. I taught myself these stuff bar experience. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about g++, then you would use the -L and -l hook. For instance:

```
g++ -o prog main.cpp -L/usr/local/lib/ -llibname
```

where whatever goes after `-L` is a path where your .lib files are located. If they're found at several different directories, you would use a semicolon (;) to separates the directories after `-L`.

Comment: added. i completely forgot about it, and then saw that @RageD posted it as soon as i submitted. also, why can't i leave comments on the question thread? is it because my rep is too low?

Comment: i didn't put .lib anywhere in my answer though.